# Sound Design Schools

Tags: school, video, video-games, movies

Hey guys! I'm a Mexican/Spanish guy (yeah, that happens a lot) graduated from audio engineering in a Mexican music production school. I'm way more interested in sound design for movies, video games, advertising, etc. I've been looking for schools, VFS seems legit, but it is really expensive and I can't work in Canada, do you guys reckon there is a high quality sound design school like that one in Europe? Preferably London based? I heard the BBC had a school but can't find it anywhere, is that true?

Answer (score 1):

Vancouver Film School has an incredible program, but is also extremely expensive.  Keep your eye out for scholarships/contests, etc.

Comment: @ ashellinthepit: Marcos said that he could not work in Canada so VFS is not an option. 

Answer (score 1):

Hola Marcos!!! es bueno saber que tambien hay mas mexicanos que comparten el gusto por el diseno en audio. Al igual que tu yo estaba buscando escuelas que impartieran algo relacionado con diseno en audio y lo mismo trate en VFS pero es extremadamente caro pero su bolsa de trabajo es increible y es lo que vale la pena.
Creo que la mejor escuela y el mejor aprendizaje por experiencia que puedes encontrar es entrando al medio, entrar a una casa productora, empezar a trabajar en proyectos y asi vas haciendo curriculum que a futuro eso te beneficia mas que un titulo de alguna escuela, y sobre todo algo que me ha servido mucho es escuchar y analizar lo que mas puedas de peliculas, documentales, spots publicitarios, videojuegos, etc, etc.
Lo que si te puedo recomendar de estudiar fuera y encontrar una escuela que imparta es que puedes encontrar una mucho mejor bolsa de trabajo y mejores posibilidades de colocarte en el medio que en Mexico.
Hace un tiempo me entere de que hay una escuela en Atlanta con el programa de diseno en audio para cine y mas accesible que VFS. http://www.scad.edu/sound-design/

Hi Mark! is good to know that there are more Mexicans who share a love of design in audio. Like you I was looking for schools that would impart something related to audio design and the same question in VFS but is extremely expensive but their job is amazing and is worth it.
I think the best school and the best learning experience you can find is entering the environment, entering a production house, start working on projects and doing so going forward that curriculum that benefits you more than a degree from a school, and especially something that has served me well is to listen and analyze what more can of films, documentaries, commercials, video games, etc, etc. What if I can recommend to study outside and find a school serving is you can find a better job and better opportunities to put yourself in the middle than in Mexico. Some time ago I found out that there is a school in Atlanta with the design program for film and audio more accessible than VFS. http://www.scad.edu/sound-design/

Answer (score 0):

What are you looking to get out of going to an audio school/taking a course?

Technically, all information and tools that you need are available without taking a course. Also, there are numerous internet communities where you can find people to work with so you can start hacking together real projects immediately, given that you have or can acquire basic recording equipment and sound effects, music and virtual instrument libraries that you may need.

Answer (score 0):

There are not so many sound schools which are specifically oriented on sound design - and what I mean here - doing sound for visuals- films, animations, games. I just wanted to stress it out, coss people use term sound design in various way... sometimes they think about music recording, sometimes about electronic/experimental music compositions. Although we use same tools in many situations - it's totally different area.

In Europe I can only think about NFTS in UK - they have sound program film oriented.

Most of the film schools haven't got sound program, and most of the sound engineering programs are music recording oriented thing.

And there's also one more thing - I guess many of european film schools don't offer programs in english